# Python ctypes using C++ members

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm trying using C++ in python.So ım trying use c++ members with python.

There my try.cpp file ..

```
extern "C"  int test(){
string a="Test!!";
int b = 5;}
```

Also dll.py ..

```
from ctypes import cdll
import os
fullpath =  os.path.abspath('try.dll')
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary(fullpath)
CALL = mydll.test()
```

Basically, ı just want using C++ members like ;

```
CALL = mydll.test()
print CALL.a # Output : Test!!
print CALL.b # Output : 5
```

Any advice? I just want use directly C++ members, but im not sure is that posible ..  *confused*

Comment: First of all, your test() function doesn't return anything.
Second of all,  test() is a function, not a C++ class.
So CALL.a  doesn't mean anything, nor does CALL.b.
Third of all, C++ strings have nothing to do with Python strings, despite having the same name, so this isn't going to work either.

Comment: I already check swig&ctypes more deeply, so ı get it why ı have to use class's.But according to me this is not comfortable to using mini projects, its looks like too higgledy-piggledy for me ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Python's C API doesn't support C++ members directly.  To do what you are proposing requires a 3-step process that is implemented for you in the SWIG program.

1. Create a python reference to a `void*` pointer that is actually a C++ object, and expose this via the C api.
2. For each member/ function of the C++ class, create a C function, exposed to Python, that uses the void * pointer and calls `(Object *)->function()`
3. Create a python class that holds the python reference to the C++ object, and that has methods and functions that call the corresponding C api functions that, in turn, pass their arguments to the C++ methods

   Translation:  use SWIG!